# Размер экрана в симуляторе ios 9

Tags: ios, экран

Хотел сделать скрины, но когда запуская симулятор под ios 9, то размеры скринов получаются странных размеров, например, под iPhone 6 - 375х667. Если запуская эмулятор под iOS 8.4, то размер становится нормальный. В чем дело?
Пробовал в настройках удалять Launch Screen File, создавал в image Assets LaunchImage и заполнял его с различными разрешениями, но ничего не помогло

Comment: а в чем проблема то? размера экрана iPhone6 в поинтах - 375х667

Comment: Почему когда я делаю скрин с iOS8 8, то получаю один размер, а когда с iOS 9, то другой размер у скрина? Получается разное разрешение у изображения

Comment: а какой размер получается на 8.4?

Comment: 750х1134 получается

Comment: т.е. в два раза больше получается

Comment: У вас видимо симулятор 8 и 9 открываются в разном масштабе - либо в меню window -> scale либо с клавиатуры Command+1 Command+2 и так далее

Comment: Совсем не подумал об этом, спасибо, поверю

Comment: ну как там дела?

Comment: Ну, не особо, если честно. Размеры симуляторов iOS 9 точно такие же, как и в iOS 8.4, но скрины получаются разных размеров. Я вот не знаю как у меня вообще поставился Xcode, если честно, просто xcode 7 под el capitano, а у меня нормально установился на Yosemite, может из-за этого беда какая-то

Comment: попробовал у себя. xcode7.1/yosemite, делал на ios8.1 и ios9.1 в масштабе 50% - везде 375x667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Симулятор нужно увеличить в размерах. Для этого нажмите cmd+1. Откроется оригинальный размер экрана. И от него скриншот будет в оригинальном размере.

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> для 100%
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> для 75%
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> для 50%

Такая ситуация только при запуске симулятора iOS 9